# huggingface expected input format

Tags: huggingface, gradio

I'm trying to invoke my test hello huggingface app via API:

```
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return "Hello " + name + "!!"

iface = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")
iface.launch()
```

I'm able to do this by using the gradio client API:

```
from gradio_client import Client

client = Client("https://toromanow-test2.hf.space/")
result = client.predict(
                "John", # str representing input in 'name' Textbox component
                api_name="/predict"
)
print(result)
```

But I'm unable to invoke it by submitting the POST request directly:

```
curl -d '{ "data": "John"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://toromanow-test2.hf.space/api/predict
```

Errors out with:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","data"],"msg":"value is not a valid list","type":"type_error.list"}]}
```

I've experimented with diferent formats but can't figure out the one what works.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone: the correct format seems to be: { "data": ["John"] }

```
curl -d '{ "data":  ["John"]}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://toromanow-test2.hf.space/api/predict
```

Comment: Thanks !
It's so awful that it is not documented anywhere, and the Gradio python client is returning a JSON file path instead of a python dict or JSON string... Hopefully we can still do HTTP requests manually.

Comment: is this still working for you?